# How to append many string to one string separated by comma?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have the following list :

```
vector<string> mylist;
```

I want to create a new string that has all the strings in mylist seperated by a comma, for years i'm writing ugly code that checks if i'm in the last string in the vector to know should i add a comma or not.

the code looks something like this :

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<mylist.size(); i++)
{
    outstring+=mylist[i];
    if(i<mylist.size()-1) // Avoiding the last comma
    {
        outstring+=",";
    }
}
```

Is there a trick to avoid the `if` statement , maybe some algorithms/iterator trick using STL ?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with that solution? You have an "extra" `if`. So what?

Comment: My (non-C++) way to do so would be to *set* `outstring` to the first item, and add a comma + next items in the loop, starting at 1.

Comment: @Jongware You still need one more `if` to check `if (mylist.size()>0)`. :P

Comment: @herohuyongtao: that's true. Also, concatenating strings is easy. If the 'copy' operator requires more work, it's far easier to insert an `if` (then I'd rather use `if (!i) continue`).

Answer (score 7):

Use `boost::algorithm::join()`:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
...
string outstring = boost::algorithm::join(mylist, ",");
```

---

<s>Alternatively, you can use (pretty ugly actually):</s>

```
stringstream  s;
copy(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(s, ","));
string outstring = s.str();  // still with the trailing delimiter ","
outstring.pop_back();        // pop back the last ","
```

Answer (score 2):

How about taking out the last comma outside of the loop? Something like the following (Thanks to @herohuyongtao for suggesting the perfect `string` member function!)

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < mylist.size(); ++i ) {
    outstring += mylist[i];
    outstring += ",";
}

outstring.pop_back();
```

Comment: Actually, you only need to do `outstring.pop_back();` in the last step.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Yes, that's simpler, thanks, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I was also unaware of string having a pop_back member function. Nice.

Comment: Oh, by the way, what if mylist is empty?

Comment: @Veritas Yes, you still need one more `if` for that. :P